# Select the amount (count) of each item and return them as a list

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a list of categories I'm showing on a page.

```
category1(21)
category2(33)
category3(0)
category4(149)
```

Each of them shows the amount of items it has. When I click on a category, it shows all the items it has. Pretty straightforward.

I use Postgresql. I wonder, what is the easier and efficient way to retrieve these numbers from db? Well, I know how to select the count of items for one item:

```
select count(1) from ....
```

But I have to display all of them for each category at the same time. How do I do that: what data structure should I use? What the query has to look like?

Of course, they should remain in the same order because at a client I have to parse them.

P.S. There are only few categories, like 10-20 and there won't be more for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "what data structure should I use"? Do you have any db yet?

Comment: @Alexander, I mean, how do I return a list (tuple) from an sql query? is there a sensible way? yes, I have a db.

Comment: Probably something like "select count(*),category_id from <table> group by category_id" ?

Comment: @Alex then show your `CREATE` for the tables, and desired results. Because, right now, it's unclear, what you asking

Comment: @Alexander, you understand everything. You're just being picky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this may help you.

You should have two tables - `1. category(id, name)` `2. items(id, name, catid)`. I just have taken minimum fields but you may add. `catid` is the reference of category `id` in the items table.

Your query should be like -

```
SELECT c.name as Category, COUNT(i.id) as Items
FROM category as c LEFT OUTER JOIN items  as i ON (c.id= i.catid)
GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY c.name
```